# Converting C strings to Pascal strings

Tags: c, string, pascal

When converting a C string into a Pascal string, why should the length of the original string be less or equal to 127 instead of 256? I understand that an unsigned int ranges from 0~256 and a signed one ranges from -128~127, but isn't the first character of a Pascal string unsigned?

Comment: `I understand that an unsigned int ranges from 0~256`..most likely, much wider.

Comment: whos says 127 or less? Wikipedia says 255 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed

Comment: The question seems lacking in basis.  On what grounds do you assert that the original string length should not exceed 127 characters?  Does Pascal really place such a limitation, or is that tied to a particular implementation?  Or is it even a real requirement at all?

Comment: Common early implementations of Pascal on PCs stored strings preceded by a single-byte length (which was unsigned, so strings could have lengths from 0 to 255). This is not a limitation of the language itself.

Comment: "Pascal string" is not standardised and everyone talking about Pascal strings talks about something slightly different. *My* Pascal strings have 4 byte sizes.

Comment: @n.m. Using Delphi and FreePascal regularly, I can say the same, but "Pascal string" is what these languages call a `ShortString`: 256 bytes, of which the byte at index 0 is the length, and the other bytes contain the text. They are typically indexed 1..255. Some varieties do have ability to restrict those to less than 255 characters, e.g. to save space in a record with `string[18]`, which then is 19 bytes in size (1 byte length + max. 18 byte text).

Comment: Where did you get that number 127? I don't know of any implementations that have that restriction, unless you means so called counted strings, but these have a fixed, explicitly declared size, e.g. `var x: string[31]`, and that size can be anything from 1 to 255.

Comment: In many context "pascal strings" are all stringtypes that can get the length and/or find the place to append in a O(1) matter. By that definition all FPC/Delphi "string" types are pascal strings. The TP string is usually refered to as TP string or shortstring.

Answer (score 2):

The Pascal string you are referring to is probably the one used in older Pascals (called `ShortString` in e.g. Delphi and FreePascal, the most popular Pascal implementations these days). That can contain 255 single-byte characters (`char` in C). **There is no need to restrict this to 127 characters**.

*Perhaps you were thinking of the fact that 255 bytes can only contain 127 UTF-16 code points. But these strings were popular in the old CP/M and DOS days, when no one knew anything about Unicode yet, and were made to contain ASCII or "Extended ASCII" (8 bit, using code pages).*

But most modern Pascal implementations allow you to use strings up to 2 GB in size. There, the length indicator is not stored as the first element anymore, just close to the text data. And these days, most of these strings can contain Unicode too, either as UTF-16 or as UTF-8, depending on the string type you choose (modern Pascal implementations have several *different* string types for different purposes, so there is not one single "Pascal string type" anymore).

Some languages do have the ability to restrict the size of a `ShortString`, as so called "counted" strings:

```
var
  s: string[18];
```

That string has a maximum of 18 bytes text data and 1 byte length data (at index 0). Such shorter strings can be used in, say, records, so they don't grow too big.

Answer (score 1):

FreePascal's wiki has a great page showing all the types of strings that Pascal (at least that implementation) supports: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types - it includes length-prefixed and null-terminated string types. None of the types on that page have a length restriction of 127.

The string type you're referring to would match `ShortString` which has a single byte prefix, however their documentation states it accepts 0-255.

I am aware of a string-type that has a *[variable-length-integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity)* prefix, which would restrict the length of the string to 127 characters if you want the in-memory representation to be binary-compatible with `ShortString`, as being 128 characters or longer would set the MSB bit to `1` which in variable-length-integers means the integer is at least 2 bytes long instead of 1 byte.

Comment: which Pascal do you know that has variable length size "prefixes" (most modern Pascals don't use prefixes anymore)?